# How can I tell traffic apart in GA from two domain names?

Tags: google-analytics

We have two domain, abc.com and xyz.com One is setup as a redirect to the other domain. Is there a way to tell in GA which domain the user used to get to the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For historical traffic, you're unlikely to be able to find this data - Google Analytics doesn't receive a hit until the webpage is loaded, and a redirect is not recorded as a referrer.

If you want to distinguish these sources in the future you could add a query parameter to your redirect code, so visits via the redirect will show differently than those directly to the destination domain. I would advise a parameter that is not in use for anything else - `redirect=true` or something like that. In particular I would avoid using a UTM parameter.

By default, with a parameter you would see `/page.html` and `/page.html?redirect=true` separately in your reports. You could likely convert the parameter into a custom dimension via a [GA filter](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?hl=en) to keep a total count but also have it easily separated into the two domains.

Comment: That won’t work for me because it is a redirect so I can’t control the parameters. I guess it’s just not possible then

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately if you can't add parameters as part of the redirect, it will be invisible to GA.